# Find out if it is the local machine

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7, firebird

I have an implementation inside my app that should run only if my executable is in the same machine as the database.

I do have a connection string wich includes the server address. In the case where it is the local machine that could be 127.0.0.1, localhost or something else (aliases for instance).

Is there a way to assertively test if the server in my connection string happens to be the local machine?

Comment: Hello Ricardo, you can check when the application tries to connect to the database if the target IP is the same as loca host, i.e. 192.168.10.20, 10.10.12.1, etc. you get the point.

Comment: What happens if you run this piece of code when the db is not local? It crashes? Or it exposes something you don't want to? Or ...?

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: It takes forever to run. If it is local it takes 2-3 minutes, if it is not it takes2-3 hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Force the `local transport protocol` (see the [connection string FAQ](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq260/)) will force a local connection.

Note that with FireBird 2.0 the underlying implementation of the `local transport protocol` changed into [XNET](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/pub/firebird/doc/README.xnet.txt).
You should not notice any differences though.

Note: don't try mixing `TCP/IP` and `local transport protocol` for InterBase 6.0 and lower, as a bug there can cause data corruption.
Mixing these two with Firebird should be fine.

--jeroen

Answer (score 0):

Just set the database's IP adress in your connection to 127.0.0.1. If it fails, it's not the local machine.

Note: this could also fail if you execute your code on computer that hosts that database + database isn't configured properly...

Comment: Indeed. If you actually mean that you app should only run when connected to a local database, why is the server address configurable?

Comment: Trivial workaround: `ssh someotherhost -L 3050:localhost:3050` forwards all traffic from 127.0.0.1:3050 to someotherhost:3050 - but the server appears to be (and is accessible) on localhost. I'm not sure this can be prevented, as there are many other ways to do such tunneling.

Comment: @David Heffernan I didn´t say that my hole app should run only locally, there is this one implementation inside my app that should be available only locally. To asure that the question won´t be ambiguous I will edit it.

Comment: @Ricardo when you get the the "one implementation inside my app that should be available only locally", always connect to loopback.

Comment: Don't connect to loopback as it can be re-routed; use the local transport protocol.

Answer (score 0):

And for a completely different approach:

Create two stored procedures in the database.

- One that returns the (configurable) full file path of a text file local to the machine running the database.
- One that writes some passed in text to this file.

In your app:

- call the stored procedure that returns the file name
- delete that file on the machine running the executable
- call the stored procedure that writes the file and feed it some unique text (preferably unique per call to the stored procedure)
- check that you can read the file from the local location and that it contains the text you fed to the stored procedure

Just be mindful of drive mapping (so check whether the drive in the returned file name is a local drive and not a mapped one) and unc file names (check that the machine name is the same as the local machine's).